# Alfresco CMIS query working with AND but not with OR

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I'm trying to get search result in alfresco using cmis query.

The below query runs fine and returns result

SELECT * FROM my:content WHERE (cmis:name Like '%a%' And my:description Like '%a%')

whereas the same query with OR condition doesn't return any result.

SELECT * FROM my:content WHERE (cmis:name Like '%a%' OR my:description Like '%a%')

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: Which CMIS endpoint are you using?

Comment: Is my:description an attribute of a type named my:content or is it defined in an aspect?

Comment: @JeffPotts cmis endpoint : http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis

Comment: @JeffPotts my description is property 
<property name="my:description">
               <title>Description</title>
               <type>d:mltext</type></property>

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct CMIS endpoint. For Alfresco, 4.2, you need to use one of the following:

ATOM Pub Binding, CMIS 1.0:

```
http://<host>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom
```

ATOM Pub Binding, CMIS 1.1:

```
http://<host>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
```

Browser (JSON) Binding, CMIS 1.1:

```
http://<host>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser
```

Using the correct binding, I cannot re-create this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For Alfresco 5, 5.0 don't support "OR" operator (!?!) :

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/intrans-metadata-query.html

> Unsupported logical operators
>
> The following logical operator is not supported: OR

But the 5.1 do :

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/intrans-metadata-query.html
Supported logical operators

> The following logical operators are supported:
>
> > AND
> >
> > NOT
> >
> > OR